# How to transform list with subelements in a dataframe R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have this:

```
res.list<-list(
    list(
        structure(list(A = 1L, B = "X2", D = 1L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L)),
        structure(list(A = 1L, B = "X3, X14, X17", D = 3L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L)),
        structure(list(A = 1L, B = "X4, X14, X17", D = 3L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L)))
    ,
    list(
        structure(list(A = 2L, B = "X17, X19", D = 2L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L)),
        structure(list(A = 2L, B = "X2, X17, X19", D = 3L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L)),
        structure(list(A = 2L, B = "X3, X17, X19", D = 3L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))))
```

What is the most efficient and generic way to do the procedure below?

```
rbind(do.call(rbind.data.frame,res.list[[1]]),
            do.call(rbind.data.frame,res.list[[2]]))
```

Best regards;

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind, unlist(res.list, recursive = FALSE))`.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier with `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(res.list)
  A            B D
1 1           X2 1
2 1 X3, X14, X17 3
3 1 X4, X14, X17 3
4 2     X17, X19 2
5 2 X2, X17, X19 3
6 2 X3, X17, X19 3
```